# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: tippy_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function

Tags: tiptap, tippyjs

Whenever I use ngx-tiptap's floating/bubble menu like this

```
<tiptap-editor [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="value"></tiptap-editor>
<tiptap-floating-menu [editor]="editor">
</tiptap-floating-menu>
```

I get an error saying.

```
 main.js:1960 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
 tippy_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function
     TypeError: tippy_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__ is not a function
     at FloatingMenuView.createTooltip (index.js:63:22)
     at FloatingMenuView.update (index.js:87:14)
     at EditorView.updatePluginViews (index.js:5326:32)
     at EditorView.updateStateInner (index.js:5273:14)
     at EditorView.updateState (index.js:5203:14)
     at Editor.dispatchTransaction (index.js:3653:19)
     at EditorView.dispatch (index.js:5555:33)`
```

I have also used mentions and a custom extension. Both of these use tippy and they work just fine.

I was expecting that the bubble/floating menu will popup. But whenever i click on the editor, I get the provided error.